# Kubernetes Ingress-nginx CORS: How to allow multiple Origins?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cors, nginx-ingress

It's currently possible to allow a single domain or subdomain but I would like to allow multiple origins. I have tried many things like adding headers with snipets but had no success.

This is my current ingress configuration:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/nginx-ingress
  uid: adcd75ab-b44b-420c-874e-abcfd1059592
  resourceVersion: '259992616'
  generation: 7
  creationTimestamp: '2020-06-10T12:15:18Z'
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: 'Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: 'https://example.com'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: 'true'
```

I also would like to extend the cors-allow-origin like:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: 'https://example.com, https://otherexample.com'
```

Is it possible to allow multiple domains in other ways?

Answer (score 2):

Ingress-nginx doesn’t support CORS with multiple origins.

However, you can try to use annotation: **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet**

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://((?:exactmatch\.com)|(?:regexmatch\.com))$") {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "$http_origin" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization" always;
    add_header "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" "Content-Length,Content-Range" always;
  }
```

Here to find more information [ingress nginx issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496).

Comment: That regexp is not secure. `https://example.com.attacker.com` would match it.

Comment: Besides, it's never necessary to allow the `Keep-Alive` request header, because this header (having a [forbidden header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)) is controlled by the browser, not by the client.

Comment: That's better, but you still shouldn't allow insecure origins (`http:` as opposed to `https:`).

Comment: As of September 2022, `cors-allow-origin` can now accept a comma-separated list of origins: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496#issuecomment-1263611772

Answer (score 2):

A some time ago, ingress-nginx allows multiple origins. See issue https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496

Example of usage:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com, https://another.com, http://localhost:8000"
```

Comment: I will test and give feedback!

Comment: We tested it in our project, and it really works )